# browser display error after request node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

i am trying to insert some data to database using node and mysql i manage to get it done, but after query response the browser loads continuously i tried pooling still nothing happens

Here is my code

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
var sql = require('mysql');
var pool  = sql.createPool({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  port      : '3306',
  database : 'node'
});

app.get('/nodeThis', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/insert.html');
});

app.post('/nodeThis', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
    var post={user_name:req.body.name1,user_what:req.body.what,user_why:req.body.why};

    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
        connection.query('INSERT INTO user SET ?', post, function(err){
            if(err){
              console.log(err);
            }else{
              console.log('succes');


            }
        });
        connection.release();
    });
});
server.listen(3000);
```

Here is how i pass the data from HTML to node

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>   
            <form action="/nodeThis" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="name1">
                <input type="text" name="what">
                <input type="text" name="why">
                <button class="boom">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: After the database operation, you aren't sending any response to the browser; you just sent an output to the console instead; the browser was waiting for a response that never came.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the database operation, you aren't sending any response to the browser; you just sent an output to the console instead; the browser was waiting for a response that never came

If you insert ***res.sendFile(__dirname + '/insert.html');*** or some other response after the ***console.log('succes');***, you'll see an output on the browser.

That being said, ***I hope this is just a proof of concept and not a production code.***

### Update Based on the Comment

#### Retrieving the number of rows affected

After running the executing the database insertion function

```
 
   db.query("insert into table", [data-to-insert], function(err, result){
   //to retrieve the number of rows affected
   var number_of_rows = result.affectedRows
})
```

the ***result*** has a property called ***affectedRows*** that allows the user to know how many rows were ***inserted***, ***updated***, or ***deleted***.

To retrieve the ***primary id*** of the inserted row *(if it has one)*, ***result*** has a property called ***insertId***.

```
 
   var id = result.insertId
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot sir it worked :). just wondering what if after inserting i would like to fetch the number of rows and send it to the browser without using res.sendFile(); it possible? just like how notifications works?

Comment: thanks a lot it worked, is there a way so i can make it work without page reload? i mean i'll have the total number or rows updated every time i add data to database and get the inserted data into a table without reloading the page just like how ajax only refresh certain div at ajax response?

Comment: Of course, you can post data through AJAX and receive the response. If you send a proper AJAX request, the above database code will still work for it.

Comment: thanks sir i'll try to make it work using that process